# SQL divide by select based on other value grouping

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum, window-functions

I would like to find the total money proportion of specific profile_id compared to the sum value of other profile_id with same area. with db_A

```
Profile_id | money | area
----------------------------
 A1        | 100   | b1
 A2        | 200   | b2
 A3        | 400   | b1
 A4        | 600   | b2
```

So I have a SQL query like

```
select profile_id, area, money, 
  sum(total_money)/
  select (
  sum(total_money)-- here I dont know how to grouping by area
  ) as area_proportion
 from db_A
 group by 1
```

and want to get result as :

```
 profile_id. |  area  | money.  | area_proportion
----------------------------------------------
 A1          | b1     |  100    |   20%
 A2          | b2     |  200    |   25%
 A3          | b1     |  400    |   80%
 A4          | b2     |  600    |   75%
```

Any help? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try and join the table with an aggregate query that computes the total money of each area, like :

```
SELECT t.*, ROUND(100 * t.money / g.money) area_proportion
FROM
    mytable t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT area, SUM(money) money from mytable GROUP BY area) g 
        ON g.area = t.area
```

If your RDBMS supports window functions (aka OLAP functions), this is even simpler :

```
SELECT 
    t.*, 
    ROUND(100 * t.money / (SUM(t.money) OVER (PARTITION BY t.area))) area_proportion
FROM mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

Following what you stated as your aim, you can go like this:

```
select profile_id, area, money, 
    sum(total_money)/
    (select sum(total_money) from db_A as dba2 where dba2.area = dba1.area and dba2.profile_id != dba1.profile_id) as area_proportion
from db_A as dba1
group by profile_id
```

Although, i assume you want to drop the `and dba2.profile_id != dba1.profile_id` part as you probably want the part one user has of all money in the area.

a more effective approach would be to create a view with a single sub-select and to join with it like this:

```
select profile_id, area, money, 
    sum(total_money) / area_total_money as area_proportion
from db_A as dba1 join (select area, sum(total_money) as area_total_money from db_A as dba2 group by area ) as area_money on dba1.area = area_money.area
group by profile_id
```